# Does PHP wait for filesystem operations (like file_put_contents) to complete before moving on?

Tags: php, filesystems

I have a question about how PHP handles filesystem operations. I'm running this code that depends on a file being created before it gets used, and it feels like when I run the code it becomes a race condition - sometimes it works, the file is created and php code uses it, sometimes it fails.

So I was wondering how php handles filesystem operations, does it send it off in the background or does it wait till the operation complete?

Comment: 'blocking' is the term you're interested in. Blocking operations cause your program to wait (or 'block') until they are complete. Non-blocking or asynchronous operations are those that are sent 'off to the background' :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, unless you open a file handle and then set it to non-blocking mode: [`stream_set_blocking()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stream-set-blocking.php)

Comment: This is actually not true. If you open and simply (f)write to it, the data is not written to disk. If fwrite uses the C function fwrite, with a high chance the data has not even reached the operating system. As @Matthew Flaschen pointed out, the data is only flushed to disk during fclose and fflush.

Comment: @ircmaxell, Answer needs elaboration.

Answer (score 9):

`file_put_contents` is equivalent to `fopen`, `fwrite`, `fclose`.  `fclose` should ensure the file is fully flushed to disk.

Comment: Actually, the only way to know for sure that the file is fully flushed to disk is to turn off write-through caching on the drives.  Otherwise, all you can tell is that the filesystem issued the write commands, not that the write was actually committed successfully to disk...

Comment: Does the `LOCK_EX` flag solve this? http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php

Answer (score 6):

Year 2013, on my common garden variety linux vps with cpanel, with default settings, with php 5.2.17, `file_put_contents` always takes ~5ms for short string lengths.

Accidentally 5ms is about the full committed write time of a high quality hdd.

```
file_put_contents($filename,'abcdefghi...~100chars',FILE_APPEND);
```

This takes ~5ms consistently. That seems to include 'blocking' and 'flushing'. So for those wondering about speed of `file_put_contents`, at least 5ms/operation on common servers 2013 04.

If you need speed, for example for some logging, [@Matthew Flaschen said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3304752):

```
file_put_contents is equivalent to fopen, fwrite, fclose. 
fclose should ensure the file is fully flushed to disk.
```

Then one needs:

```
function file_put_contents_fast() {...no fclose...}
```

But it will take some research to find out what happens if file handles are left open. [Php closes them at exit](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.flock.php), but does it really do so all the time? Even if it crashes? What happens if a file is left open by php after a crash? etc etc. After 30 minutes of php manual reading and googling, there was no mention of such and its consequences.

Comment: I wonder why file_put_contents does not have a option to flush file to immediatly write it on disk.

Answer (score 3):

PHP should wait until the process is completed. But not knowing how you are implementing the operations it is hard to say. If you can post an example code that you are using that would be helpful so we can help you figure out why it is not working properly.

Comment: should, but seems not true.  I just had issue where files seems not yet fully written before another set of code run to process them which caused weird issue