# Is file_put_contents synchronous with NFS

Tags: php, nfs

My question is the following:

Is PHP's `file_put_contents()` function synchronous with NFS and if yes, is it in any circumstances? For instance, if the remote file system I interact with through NFS can be either EXT3 or NFS, is that an important factor to make sure `file_put_contents()` is synchronous?

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does PHP wait for filesystem operations (like file\_put\_contents) to complete before moving on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304727/does-php-wait-for-filesystem-operations-like-file-put-contents-to-complete-bef)

Comment: I know more focus on NFS to make sure it's not a duplicate question. Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. PHP wouldn't even know that it's writing to NFS. It uses the operating system's [syscalls](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_call) for file system access. It's the OS'es duty to abstract file system calls to user space applications, this includes remote file systems such as NFS.
2. Write operations in PHP are synchroneous. PHP waits for the syscall to finish to process its result. However, [NFS, like other file systems, can be mounted asynchroneously](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146620/difference-between-sync-and-async-mount-options), so that the FS subsystem may report a successful write when in fact it has only cached the data for a later write. This is a huge performance gain, but can cause loss of data when the server crashes.

However, NFS `sync`/`async` is a bit different.

Quoting the relevant section of `man 5 nfs`,

> The NFS client treats the sync mount option differently than some other file systems […]. If neither sync nor async is specified (or if the async option is specified), the NFS client delays sending application writes to the server until any of these events occur:
>
> - Memory pressure forces reclamation of system memory resources.
> - An application flushes file data explicitly with sync(2), msync(2), or fsync(3).
> - An application closes a file with close(2).
> - The file is locked/unlocked via fcntl(2).
>
> In other words, under normal circumstances, data written by an
>   application may not immediately appear on the server that hosts the
>   file.
>
> If the *sync* option is specified on a mount point, any system call that
>   writes data to files on that mount point causes that data to be
>   flushed to the server before the system call returns control to user
>   space.  This provides greater data cache coherence among clients, but
>   at a significant performance cost.
>
> If the *sync* option is specified on a mount point, any system call that
>   writes data to files on that mount point causes that data to be
>   flushed to the server before the system call returns control to user
>   space. This provides greater data cache coherence among clients, but
>   at a significant performance cost.

Applying this to your question, this means: If your NFS is mounted with `sync`, each chunk of data is written to the remote system instantly. With `async`, the file is written to the remote system when `file_put_contents` has finished.

As `file_put_contents` works atomically and finishes with `fclose` anyway, it doesn't matter for you if NFS is mounted `sync` or `async` – when `file_put_contents` finishes, the data has been written to the remote file system. Should the remote server crash, PHP will throw an error anyway. There's no advantage with `sync` in this scenario.

And especially if you're working with big files, `sync` would be very hurtful, because each chunk of data will create a huge overhead of *userspace → kernel → network → remote kernel → remote filesystem* communication.

Therefore you should mount NFS with the `async` option, which is the default anyway.

By the way, the NFS client doesn't know if the remote partition is Ext3 or whatever. It's just NFS, and can as such be treated just like any POSIX-compliant file system.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this response. Do you know where information can be found about NFS and how to configure it asynchroneously ?

Comment: `man 5 nfs` ;) TL;DR: You can toggle sync/async through the mount options. See the link I've posted or google yourself: https://www.google.com/search?q=nfs+async Also might want to look into the topic of write(-through/-back) caching.