# php - for loop repeating itself / going out of sequence

Tags: php, json, for-loop, fwrite

I'm very new to PHP, making errors and learning as I go. Please be gentle! :)

I want to access some data from Blizzard.com's API. For this particular data set, it's not a block of data in JSON, rather each object has it's own URL to access. I estimate that there are approx 150000 objects, however I don't know the start or end points of the number range. So I'm having to assume 1 and work past the highest number I know (269065)

To get the data, I need to access each object's data via a JSON file, which I read, get the contents of & drop in to a text file (this could be written as an insert in to a SQL db too, as I'm able to do this if it's the text file that's the issue). But to be honest, I would love to get to the bottom of why this is happening as much as anything!

I wasn't going to try and run ~250000 iterations in a for loop, I thought I'd try something I considered small, 2000.

The for loop starts with $a as 1, uses $a as part of the URL, loads & decodes the JSON, checks to see if the first field (ID) in the object is set, if it is, it writes a few fields to data.txt & if the first field (ID) isn't set it just writes $a to data.txt (so I know it's a null for other purposes not outlined here).

Simple! Or so I thought, after approx after 183 iterations, the data written to the text file goes awry as seen by the quote below. It is out of sequence and starts at 1 again, then back to 184 ad nauseam. The loop then seems to be locked in some kind of infinite loop of running, outputting in a random order until I close the page 10-20 minutes later.

I have obviously made a big mistake! But I have no idea what I have done wrong to have caused this. During my attempts I have rewritten the code with new variable names, so a new text does not conflict with code that could be running in memory.

I've tried resetting variables to blank at the end of the loop in case it something was being reused that was causing a problem.

If anyone could point out any errors in my code, or suggest something for me to look in to, to handle bigger loops that would be brilliant. I am assuming my issue may be a time out or memory problem. But I don't know where to start & was hoping I'd find some suggestions here.

If it's relevant, I am using 000webhostapp.com as my host provider for now, until I get some paid for hosting.

> 1 ... 182 183 1 184 2 3 185 4 186 5 187 6 188 7 189 190 8 191

```
for ($a = 1; $a <= 2000; $a++)      {
    $json = "https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/recipe/".$a."?locale=en_GB&<MYPRIVATEAPIKEY>";
    $contents = file_get_contents($json);
    $data = json_decode($contents,true);

        if (isset($data['id'])) {
            $file = fopen("data.txt","a");
            fwrite($file,$data['id'].",'".$data['name']."'\n");
            fclose($file);
        } else {    
            $file = fopen("data.txt","a");
            fwrite($file,$a."\n");
            fclose($file);  
        }
}
```

The content of the file I'm trying to access is

> {"id":33994,"name":"Precise Strikes","profession":"Enchanting","icon":"spell_holy_greaterheal"}

**I scrapped the original plan and wrote this instead. Thank you again who took the time out of their day to help and offer suggestions!**

```
$b = $mysqli->query("SELECT id FROM `static_recipes` order by id desc LIMIT 1;")->fetch_object()->id;

if (empty($b)) {$b=1;};
$count = $b+101;

$write = [];
for ($a = $b+1; $a < $count; $a++)      {
     $json = "https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/recipe/".$a."?locale=en_GB&apikey=";
     $contents = @file_get_contents($json);
     $data = json_decode($contents,true);
     if (isset($data['id'])) {
     $write [] = "(".$data['id'].",'".addslashes($data['name'])."','".addslashes($data['profession'])."','".addslashes($data['icon'])."')";

 } else {    
   $write [] = "(".$a.",'a','a','a'".")";
 }
} 
$SQL = ('INSERT INTO `static_recipes` (id, name, profession, icon) VALUES '.implode(',', $write));
$mysqli->query($SQL);
$mysqli->close();
```

Comment: We can't help much without seeing the content of your data. I would suggest that opening and closing this file 2000 is a waste of resources though...

Comment: Open the file once before you start the loop and only close after the loop is finished. There is no reason to open and close it each time through the loop. You're going to be appending to it regardless.

Comment: are you running this from cli , ie single instance ?  if not (like trigger via an http server) , you could have two instances or more running in parallel.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I'll try it now.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg  yeah, I am running it as a single instance to start with, until I'm sure that I have the most effiicient / low foot print code before I go nuts with it.  I will try your suggest to run in parallel.

Comment: Hi @miken32, here is the content {"id":33994,"name":"Precise Strikes","profession":"Enchanting","icon":"spell_holy_greaterheal"} thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

```
$write = [];
for ($a = 1; $a <= 2000; $a++)      {
    $json = "https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/".$a."?locale=en_GB&<MYPRIVATEAPIKEY>";
    $contents = file_get_contents($json);
    $data = json_decode($contents,true);
    if (isset($data['id'])) {
      $write [] = $data['id'].",'".$data['name']."'\n";
    } else {    
      $write [] = $a."\n";
    }
} 
$file = fopen("data.txt","a");
fwrite($file, implode('', $write));
fclose($file);
```

Also, why you are think what some IDS isn't duplicated at several "https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/[N]" urls data?

Also if you are `I wasn't going to try and run ~250000` think about `curl_multi_init()`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-multi-init.php

Comment: Thank you for the new code suggestion Николай Лубышев. The ID has a one to one relationship within the game of World of Warcraft. Each ID represents an object in game. I will also look & start learning cURL, thank you!

Comment: This worked, putting the data in an array and inserting that has overcome the problem of data going out of sequence and repeating. Thank you! Also thank you to all that helped & had similar suggestions.

Comment: Well! It didn't work after all, I used the above code & had a range of $a = 2000; $a <=3000; it got to 2998, 2999, 3000,then went back to 2000 again & looped 
 up to 3000, and restarted at 2000 for 1 1/2 hours! I'm wondering if this is a memory stack problem, an unsigned data type problem or maybe a http header issue. I am going to completely change my direction on this, write it directly to the database in chunks of 20 rows, re-reading the latest ID in the DB & set that to $a, having a cron job run every minute, to blast through this.

Comment: I cant help without soirce code. check `re-reading the latest ID in the DB`

Comment: `having a cron job run every minute` -- that's!
Make a singleton-cron-job. Set some flag what job is already is runnig and check it before some process. If flag dont is set - processing else - exit.
Aftrer processing - unset the flag.

Comment: Hi Николай Лубышев the source code & JSON contents are in my original post. I just did not include my SQLI log in details and <?PHP ?> tags. The source code is very small because it was doing one simple job :)) The Cron job is working now. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see anything obviously wrong with your code, can't run it though as I don't have the JSON

It could be possible that there is some kind of race condition since you're opening and closing the same file hundreds of times very quickly.

File operations might seem atomic but not necessarily so - here's an interesting SO thread:

[Does PHP wait for filesystem operations (like file_put_contents) to complete before moving on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3304727/does-php-wait-for-filesystem-operations-like-file-put-contents-to-complete-bef)

Like some others' suggested - maybe just open the file before you enter the loop then close the file when the loop breaks.

I'd try it first and see if it helps.

Comment: I'll try the suggestions, thank you for the article as well.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in your original code that would cause that sort of behaviour. PHP will not arbitrarily change the value of a variable. You are opening this file in append mode, are you certain that you're not looking at old data? Maybe output some debug messages as you process the data. It's likely you'd run up against some rate limiting on the API server, so putting a pause in there somewhere may improve reliability.

The only substantive change I'd suggest to your code is opening the file once and closing it when you're done.

```
$file = fopen("data_1_2000.txt", "w");
for ($a = 1; $a <= 2000; $a++)      {
    $json = "https://eu.api.battle.net/wow/recipe/$a?locale=en_GB&<MYPRIVATEAPIKEY>";
    $contents = file_get_contents($json);
    $data = json_decode($contents, true);
    if (!empty($data['id'])) {
        $data["name"] = str_replace("'", "\\'", $data["name"]);
        $record = "$data[id],'$data[name]'";
    } else {
        $record = $a;
    }
    fwrite($file, "$record\n");
    sleep(1);
    echo "$a "; if ($a % 50 === 0) echo "\n";
}
fclose($file);
```

Comment: Yeah I agree, I've pegged it down to do with me not handling the http header responses. I've took the file_get_contents out & ran the code with big loops without an issue. The cron job/small loop seems to be working most of the time. I can handle repeats in the SQL DB a lot easier than a text file. I just thought it would of been easier to of made the CSV, also it let me try something new. Turns out it was a bit of PITA! Thanks for your help!